# Tabulator v5 maxHeight 100% not working when used inside flex box?

Tags: flexbox, tabulator

Goal is getting table-bottom and footer within the main layout. (light gray)

[image]

You find the puzzle here https://codepen.io/ironirc/pen/ExwQMLX

html structure:

```
<div style="height:300px;background-color:#555;padding:10px">
  <div class="col-layout">
    <div class="header">This is the header</div>
    <div class="table-wrapper">
      <div class="table" id="userTable">Table placeholder</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">This is the footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.col-layout {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  align-content: stretch;
  background-color: #999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  background-color: #ff5c61;
}
.table-wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}
.table {
  background-color: #4cd1a4;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #5ebeff;
}
```

Js omitted (see code pen)

Removing the table wrapper (black) solves the problem, but in my case I need it.

Answer (score 0):

change the the `height: 300px;` to `height: auto;`

(the first div you have in the code)

```html
<div style="height:auto;background-color:#555;padding:10px">
```

here the code

```js
const data = [{
    email: "me@mail.com",
    verified: true,
    roles: ["super"],
    language: "en"
  },
  {
    email: "you@mail.com",
    verified: true,
    roles: ["super"],
    language: "en"
  },
  {
    email: "them@mail.com",
    verified: true,
    roles: ["super"],
    language: "en"
  },
  {
    email: "me@mail.com",
    verified: true,
    roles: ["super"],
    language: "en"
  },
  {
    email: "you@mail.com",
    verified: true,
    roles: ["super"],
    language: "en"
  },
  {
    email: "them@mail.com",
    verified: true,
    roles: ["super"],
    language: "en"
  },
  {
    email: "me@mail.com",
    verified: true,
    roles: ["super"],
    language: "en"
  },
  {
    email: "you@mail.com",
    verified: true,
    roles: ["super"],
    language: "en"
  },
  {
    email: "them@mail.com",
    verified: true,
    roles: ["super"],
    language: "en"
  },
  {
    email: "me@mail.com",
    verified: true,
    roles: ["super"],
    language: "en"
  },
  {
    email: "you@mail.com",
    verified: true,
    roles: ["super"],
    language: "en"
  },
  {
    email: "them@mail.com",
    verified: true,
    roles: ["super"],
    language: "en"
  }
];

(async function() {
  const mod = await
  import (
    "https://cdn.skypack.dev/pin/tabulator-tables@v5.0.7-vGtDkKjV9T1fmkgGx42u/mode=imports/optimized/tabulator-tables.js"
  );

  const userTable = new mod.TabulatorFull(
    document.getElementById("userTable"), {
      columns: [{
          title: "Email",
          field: "email",
          headerTooltip: "Account EMail"
        },
        {
          title: "Verified",
          field: "verified",
          formatter: "tickCross"
        },
        {
          title: "Language",
          field: "language"
        },
        {
          field: "roles",
          title: "Roles"
        }
      ],
      layout: "fitDataFill",
      maxHeight: "100%"
    }
  );

  userTable.on("tableBuilt", function() {
    userTable.setData(data);
  });
})();
```

```css
.col-layout {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  align-content: stretch;
  background-color: #999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-color: #ff5c61;
}

.table-wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.table {
  background-color: #4cd1a4;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #5ebeff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="height:auto;background-color:#555;padding:10px">
    <div class="col-layout">
      <div class="header">This is the header</div>
      <div class="table-wrapper">
        <div class="table" id="userTable">Table placeholder</div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">This is the footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Laaouatni. However, with your solution you turned the constraining puzzle upside down. The intention is to make the tabulator behave so that it fits inside given height.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, this is because of the way that flex layouts work, they will not shrink below the smallest size of the content, so once the table has been rendered it will not allow it to get smaller.

You should `absolutely` position a containing div in the flexed div, with `top:0`, `left:0`, `height:100%`, `width:100%`. Then stick your Tabulator inside that, it will then allow the flex layout to resize and the table to fit